# diet for six pack for vegiterian

Tags: diet, vegetarian

this question is a extension of my pervious question [Shape up body with heavy weights or light weights](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11413/shape-up-body-with-heavy-weights-or-light-weights)

I have google about the diet to have the six pack and I have learned that I need to break up my eating habit to 6 times a day with small amount of food. I am a **pure vegiterian**(I don't even eat egg) 
Can you guide me about the food I can take to have six pack?

Comment: Nutrition is off topic here, according to the [faq]. The basics on why and how you can achieve the necessary physique for a six pack (get rid of bodyfat) has been covered often enough and does not change if you are a vegan, vegetarian or not.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Nutrition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition?referrer=60gsuPikc4OEtIT3irFQMg2) proposal on Area51.